# Don't show acronyms description in the text

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I have just finished writing my thesis, and I want to add a list of acronyms; however, I don't want that the description of the acronym appears in the text. For example:

```
usepackage[nonumberlist, acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{VMs}{VMs}{ Machines virtuelles} 
 \begin{document}
  \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Liste des abbréviations]
```

I don"t want that "Machines virtuelles" appears in my text as shown in the picture, and also I need to not show the red color of the acronym in my text. Noting that I am using the Overleaf platform.
[image: picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glossaries` usually displays the long and the short from of an acronym on the first use of said acronym and only uses the short from for all following uses (first use flag). To overcome this behaviour, either add `\glsunsetall` to the preamble (after your `\newacronym` commands). Alternatively, you could also switch to `glossaries-extra` which offers the abbreviation style `short`. You can use it as follows: `\usepackage[nonumberlist,automake]{glossaries-extra} \setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short}`.

Regarding the red color. I guess, you also load the `hyperref` package as follows:  `\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}`. Thus, the abbreviation (and its unwanded long form) are colored red and are also a hyperlink to the list of abbreviations. If you want to keep the hyperlink and just want to hide the color, use `\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}`. If you want to hide the color and disable the hyperlinks, use `\glsdisablehyper`.